# How update data from azure iot hub in azure MSSql table by conditions with azure stream analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am working on Azure, there is a SQL Server database with one table and iot hub receive date from iot hub. I have to check if the data are currently existing in the database and store them if not otherwise update the old data in the table.

Not sample data is not exist & i don't want to put data sample. I am clear the question. I got the data on iot hub ...In Azure have a azure-stream-analytics service who provide the platform to write the query to save data in database who is coming from iot hub. I have also SQL Server database on Azure where I save the data. So in one table, I need to update the row on particular id which is coming from iot hub so its means i know what is unique id .so base on that unique id i want update the row. I wrote a query to save data in the database.

I tried this T-SQL query but it doesn't work. If anyone know about that please help me.

```
SELECT
    Alarms
INTO
    AlarmsOutput
FROM
    AlarmsInput
```

But I want to update the row so i want to know is it possible to write the update query if know please mention here

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If new data arrives in IoT Hub, how would those data samples already exist? If you really needed to do this, you'd need to feed your samples to some code that you have (maybe an Azure Function or some other event-driven code?), which would need to query your table for every single sample (which could have an enormous impact on your database resource usage). In any case, your question, as written, is very broad and a bit unclear. Please edit to be more specific, and to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: You could place an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the target table or view that would update existing rows and insert new ones.

Comment: Thanks I write the trigger to update my main table .Thanks its solve my problem